# ESXI upgrade remotley

Tags: vmware-esxi, upgrade

I'm planning to upgrade one of our esxi host and I would like to do this remotely because of distance problems. Is it possible to do this? The host is an ESXi4 what I would like to upgrade to Esxi5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vCener Server to upgrade ESXi host with VUM: Vmware Update Manager to update esxi4 to esxi5

See the below instructions

http://www.sysadmintutorials.com/tutorials/vmware-vsphere-5-x/vcenter-5-x/update-manager/esxi-4-upgrade-to-esxi-5-using-update-manager/

Comment: thanks for your feedback, I have vsphere but this upgrade option is not present over there which client I should download

Comment: you Need ESXi5 Iso Image. That's it! For baseline attachment and upgrade options. Since you are doing it using VUM, the ISO image downloaded of ESXi5 is just what you wanted.